# Deploy WebApplication on localhost using IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am using Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7 and IIS. I have written a small WebApplication and I want to publish the WebApplication in the localhost. So I click on the project in Visual Studio => Publish => choose File Sytem => Local IIS. After that, I get an error:

> To access local IIS Web sites, you
>   must install the following IIS
>   components:
>
> ```
>   IIS 6 Metabase and IIS 6 Configuration Compatibility
>   ASP.NET
> ```
>
> In addition, you must run Visual
>   Studio in the context of an
>   administrator account.
>
> For more information, Press F1.

This topic is new for me, so I am a beginner. What exactly must I do to solve this error? Please help me. :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start -> Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features On Or Off -> IIS -> Web Management tools -> IIS 6 Management Compatibility

Woot!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need more rights on your development box.  Are you in the administrator's group?